Power Platform Connectors using explicit connections using AD Account are always encountering Fix Connections
may somebody help me explain why explicit connectors in Power Platform using our AD Account are always encountering Fix Connections issues. It always always the reason why our Power Automate run stopped. Can you help me a solution how to fix it or is there any workaround to prevent this from happening? Thanks

I always try to Fix connection but after several days it will happen again.
